# Shorter command for deleting files

Tags: bash, files, scripting

Our web server was originally maintained by a different company. They wrote a short script to clean out cache files. Their file has several lines that read like this:

```
/usr/bin/find /var/www/cache/blah/ |xargs /bin/rm -f >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Is there any reason why they couldn't just write:

```
/bin/rm -f /var/www/cache/blah/*
```

to delete the files? I can see using `find` when you need a particular criteria, but I can't seem to find one in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few differences in the behavior of the command lines:

1. The `find` command line would delete files *recursively in subdirectories*, the `rm` command line wouldn't.
   You need to consider whether or not you want to recurse.
2. The `find` command line would delete all files, if possible. The `rm` command line *might skip files* based on the shell's settings like `GLOBIGNORE`.
   You need to consider whether or not there might be filenames that might be accidentally ignored in pathname expansion.
3. The `find` command line would *succeed for any number of files*. The `rm` command line *might fail* if the pathname expansion creates a *command line* that is *too long* (bigger than the system supports). Some systems have limits on this.
   You need to consider how many files might need to be deleted.
4. The `find` command line ignores all output messages (using the redirections to `>/dev/null`). The `rm` command line prints the output messages.
   You need to consider what should happen with the messages.

If these differences do not matter to you, `/bin/rm -f /var/www/cache/blah/*` will work for you.

If only files are to be removed, and directories are to be retained, I would actually use

```
/usr/bin/find /var/www/cache/blah/ -not -type d -exec /bin/rm -f -- {} + >/dev/null 2>&1
```

or

```
/usr/bin/find /var/www/cache/blah/ -type f -exec /bin/rm -f -- {} + >/dev/null 2>&1
```

whatever suits your purpose, both have pros and cons.

`-exec command {} +` works just like `xargs`, but is slightly more efficient. The `--` prevents that `rm` falls over if one of the filenames starts with `-`. Also, `xargs` was used in a way that makes too many assumptions about filenames. Special characters like space would actually break the simple invocation of `xargs`. Something like `find ... -print0 | xargs -0` would be required, and then the `find -exec command {} +` is just much simpler.

Comment: `xargs` will fail with filename contains special characters, `find -exec ..` doesn't.

Comment: You should also note that `-not` and `-print0` is not POSIX. They only work in some implement like GNU `find` or FreeBSD `find`.

Comment: @Christian Hujer, thank you, that does explain it. In this case there aren't ever any sub directories so I found it kind of odd, but the explanation above does describe possible scenarios.

Comment: While the original code in the question is completely flawed from a security point of view, yours also is as it's similar for instance to [CVE-2011-0441](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=618489).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Can we prevent this with POSIX standard?

Answer (score 8):

Some reasons I can think about why they used `find` + `xargs`:

- Handling the case when you have too many cache files, leading to an error if you run only one `rm` command.
- Globbing `*` does not expand hidden files.
- Working recursively.

But this `find` + `xargs` is not efficient, since when they didn't add any filter, so `find` result will contain directories along with files. Running `/bin/rm -f` on a directory leads to an error, that's why the `stderr` and `stdout` are redirected to `/dev/null`. And with files those name contains special characters, the command will also fail.

An improved solution can be:

```
find /var/www/cache/blah -type f -exec rm -f -- {} +
```

This is more efficient, doing all works with `find`, minimum forking of `rm` and POSIXly.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers miss three points:

Don't ever do this:

```
/usr/bin/find /var/www/cache/blah/ |xargs /bin/rm -f >/dev/null 2>&1
```

because when you have a file with a space in it, `rm` will attempt to remove two files, with surprising results.

If you insist on doing it this way, assuming you are using GNU `find` and `xargs`, you want:

```
/usr/bin/find /var/www/cache/blah/ -print0 | xargs -0 /bin/rm -f >/dev/null 2>&1
```

which zero terminates the files (and expects zero termination in xargs).

Secondly, are you trying to delete directories or not? If not, you want '-type f'. If so, you want 'rm -rf' as `rm` without `-r` will not remove a directory.

But most importantly, OP asked for a shorter method, and the answers appear to be longer. How about:

```
/usr/bin/find /var/www/cache/blah/ -delete
```

I believe `-delete` is a GNU extension so check your version of `find` supports it.

Comment: Don't forget that `-print0` and `-0` are also GNU extensions.  Cleaning empty sub-directories can be done with a second `find` command doing a depth-first search for directories and executing `rmdir` with errors going to `/dev/null`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks - I've added a comment re `-print0` and `-0`